# Return the rows with data only

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have a table with column of type character varying where I am storing some numbers. How to check if the column is holding values greater than zero (`>0`).

Table (table1):

```
ID  Item_Number    Item_Name
10   10909         Item10
11   12344         Item10
12   EN-890        Item89
13   1234          Item90
14                 Item10
15                 Item10
16   893           Item10
17   780           Item10
18   12,13,15      Item10
19   12312         Item12
```

From the above table, ID is of type integer, ItemNumber is of type character varying, ItemName is of type character varying. I want to select and show all the data with ItemNumber greater than zero and ItemName is equal to Item10.

Below is the query i have used:

```
SELECT Item_Number AS itemNumber,
       Item_Name AS itemName
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.item_number::integer > 0
  AND t1.item_name='Item10';
```

How to show only the rows holding `item_number>0 and item_name ='Item10'`

With my above query, it is returning the blank rows with no data also.

Comment: `EN-890` is it `>0` or `<0`?

Comment: I should not consider those, i have to check only for Item_name = 'Item10' and item_number for that Item10 should be greater thanzero..@Ilya Bursov

Comment: Also add third condition as AND  t1.item_number IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 2):

You can convert conditionally to a number:

```
where (case when t1.item_number ~ '^[0-9]+$'
            then t1.item_number::integer
       end) > 0 and
      t1.item_name = 'Item10';
```